# Get Empty combo field value from form.getValues() in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am having form control with two combo box(one is editable), iam unable to get the field value pair when the combo is empty.

Is there any property to say the combo, to send the empty value if combo is reset to empty.

I.E for example:

Consider first combo is Country with name property 'country' and the

Second combo is State with name property 'state' with editable property.

when state combo is not selected or selected and cleared

i am getting form.getvalue() as {country:'xxx'}

But i need as {country:'xxx',state:''}

How to get this output, is there any property in form or combo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a default value on the field, just set it to an empty string...

`value: ''`

Here is an example (open your firebug console to see the output of `getValues()`)

http://jsfiddle.net/jaitsu/GLARt/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        id: 'searchValue',
        value:'' // this way value is empty string
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From api docs the parameter list of `form.getValues()` is:

```
getValues( [Boolean asString], [Boolean dirtyOnly], [Boolean includeEmptyText] )
```

Use this method in the following way:

```
form.getValues(false, false, true);
```

and during submit enable `submitEmptyText : true`.